# Imaginary part of Log laplacian

Tags: complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, vector-analysis, complex-integration

I'm confused about how to calculate $\nabla^2 \log z$, where $z=re^{i\theta}$ is a complex number. My calculations return 
$$
\nabla^2 \log z = 2\pi\frac{\delta(r)}{r} [\delta(\theta) + i \Theta(\theta)]
$$
, where $\delta$ is the dirac delta and $\Theta$ is the step function (Heaviside).

I can find no errors in the above expression, but when I try to check the above result by using vector calculus, I have on the left side 
$$
\int_A da \nabla^2 \log z = \mbox{using stokes theorem} =  \int_{\partial A} d\vec{l} \cdot \vec{\nabla} \log z = 2\pi
$$
where I choose $A$ a circle of radius $A$. By the other hand, the right hand side gives
$$
2\pi(1+2\pi i)
$$
Does anyone has a clue about what am I doing wrong?

EDIT

As I was discussing with geodude below, my main concern is the correctness of the imaginary part of $\nabla^2 \log z$. The real part is ok, because it appears everywhere in electrostatics and I've verified that.

So, to obtain the full solution, I've performed as following:

Given $\log(z-z')$, since it is singular at $z=z'$, I've used a series expansions for the log. $\log(z-z') = (A-B) \Theta(r-r') + B$, where 
$$
A = \log r + i \theta - \sum_{m=1}^\infty \frac{1}{m} \left(\frac{r'}{r}\right)^m e^{im(\theta'-\theta)} \\
B = \log r' + i \theta' - \sum_{m=1}^\infty \frac{1}{m} \left(\frac{r'}{r}\right)^m e^{im(\theta-\theta')}
$$

Since $\nabla^2 B = 0$, only the term involving (A-B) must be calculated, and after turning the machinery I've obtained the equation shown at the top.

Comment: How did you get to that formula? I would say that it is simply $2\pi i\delta(r)$...

Comment: You say the Laplacian? It is a 1 page calculation with the method I've choosen... I've found quite hard with usual procedures one can find around, and I'm precisely interested in the imaginary part, which almost everybody neglects

Comment: The problem is that the Heaviside step function of $\theta$ depends *heavily* on which instance of $\theta$ you choose.

Comment: Sorry... But I've simplified somethings also. Initially it was $log(u-u')$, and from there the $\Theta(\theta)$ appears

Comment: Also, am I wrong or is $\nabla \log z= 1/z$, whose integral around the circle is $2\pi i$?

Comment: It is $\int_{\partial c} dz \nabla \log z = 2\pi i$...
As far as I've seen, the real part of the expression I've derived is ok, because it is the same that appears in electrostatics.

Comment: This is very interesting, and I can't seem to find it *anywhere*!

Comment: It is tricky... I've been in this one for a few days by now. But in fact my main concern is the correct formula for the Laplacian... That $\Theta$ concerns me, and it would be much better for my work if it was a $\delta$...

Comment: Well, I would like at least to see the method you used!

Comment: Wait a second...

Comment: I looked in all my references, no mention at all about the Laplacian of the logarithm, only its real part in a book on electrodynamics. If anyone has any reference, please post it here!

Comment: Hehehe I had the same problem... Everybody talks about the real part only, and I'm not sure about what happens with the imaginary part...
It must be something really complicated for nobody commenting it, and probably it is not what I've shown above...
I guess that the only clue is that the function associated with the imaginary part is odd in $\theta$ or $0$, because when integrated in $\theta$ it gives 0

Comment: Is there anything like a "harmonic dual" for distributions?

Comment: Sorry, but I've not understood that... What's an harmonic dual?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_conjugate

Comment: Now I've understood your point. But it seems a bit hard to me that such thing exist for us to directly extend the known $\delta$. The harmonic dual seems to require well-behaved topology.
geodude, thanks for your help, but I have to go now...